# Is document.getCSSCanvasContext a native javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Why is this code is giving me the error "document.getCSSCanvasContext is not a function". I'm trying to make my css background a javascript canvas.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
div { background: -webkit-canvas(squares); width:600px; height:600px; border:2px solid black }
</style>
<script type="application/x-javascript">
function draw(w, h) { var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext("2d", "squares", w, h); ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)"; ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50); ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)"; ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50); }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="draw(300, 300)">
<div/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that it's deprecated and removed. If you explain what you're trying to do here, I'm sure there is another way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I'm trying to make my css background a javascript canvas so I can animate the background

Comment: OK--you might want to open a new question and ask specifically about that, with a clear specification (maybe an output image/sketch showing what your goal is). You can show this code as your attempted solution explaining that the func was deprecated. Good luck!

Comment: I'll do that! Thank you!